# Java - allow access to files during I/O

Tags: java, file-io, read-write

Is there any way to allow access to files while they are being used in Java?

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String data = "";
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    data += line;
}
bw.write(data + msg);
br.close();
bw.close();
```

Otherwise, I need to do something like that each time I want to add a single line to a text file...

Thanks!

To clarify: I need external programs to be able to access the file while Java is writing to it. I do NOT want to use the code above each time I need to add a line to the file. I do want to open a filewriter from the start, and append whenever I need to (but as I said, I need to allow external programs access, so this won't work!).

Comment: What is it you would like to do?

Comment: "Is there any way to allow access to files while they are being used in Java?"

Comment: You could try and use a Selector in the NIO libary.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906433/nio-server-not-able-to-listen-to-client

Comment: @Marc Noon - looking into it, thanks EDIT: Hmm, looks complex. Are there really no simpler solutions?

Comment: @Marc Noon FileChannels are not SelectableChannels. Selectors cannot possibly solve this. The link you posted is irrelevant too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are under Windows there is no solution. It is Windows that is blocking concurrent access to the file, not Java.

Comment: Ok, that's too bad. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -2):

In the concepts of **java.nio** you're able to non-blocking file access.

Comment: I've looked around and that seems like the way to go. Do you happen to have any tutorials/code snippets for file i/o?

Comment: No you're not. There is no such thing as non-blocking file access in Java. @guywhoneedsahand ignore this.

Comment: And even if there was, it wouldn't help you with locking. Non-blocking means it won't block the thread if there is no data immediately available, it doesn't bypass locks.

Comment: @guywhoneedsahand http://linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_030.htm - in this article explains how to lock some parts of your file, while other part of file still be accessible to other processes (other JVM's or native processes). But, as I understood - locking is OS-dependent.